# rewrite rules add a folder in the path

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have to do some url rewritting for custom post types.
I have 2 custom post types: *portfolios* and *locations*.

What I need to change is the url like this:

```
current: http://example.com/portfolios/user1/
Should change to: http://example.com/production/portfolios/user1/

current: http://example.com/locations/loc1/
should change to: http://example.com/production/locations/loc1/
```

How can I use `add_rewrite_rules`? Would it be better to use `generate_rewrite_rules`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that portfolios and locations are two custom types right?

In this case you have to change the slug options inside the custom type registration:

```
register_post_type( 'portfolios', array(
    ...
    'rewrite' => array("slug" => "/production/portfolios", "with_front" => false),
) );
```

Comment: ohh, in fact i was using 'rewrite' => array("slug" to change the custom post name.Sometimes the easier solutions are the best :)